# Shipping for Downloadable product - Magento

Tags: magento

I have one downloadable product in which I have option to sent medie. If user choose to media along with my downloadable product I want shipping option enable in my checkout. How can I achive this any idea ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: want it by module or mage core?

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild your product.

Use a simple product and a downloadble.

Build up a configurable product from the two.

Then depending on the option the user chooses, he get's a simple product (with shipping) or a downloadable without.

Comment: I think about this solution But there is problem, My product is downloadeble. If any user choose with media, it require to downloadable product and physical media as well, so if user choose media, in simple product i am not able to provide product virtually, Anyways, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @KameshJungi You can use a bundled product, so he gets both a simple and a downloadable product when choosing the media option.